Attempting to create GravityZone that affects Player Character Controller
Attempting to have a platform exhibit gravity behaviors. Here is what I have...
I have a Player that has a Character Controller Component (Not rigidbody)
Now I also have this script that I took from a tutorial, however it requires a Rigidbody - a component I am not using
Additionally the GravityZone is a Collider
Result - A Platform that utilizes gravity behavior to push the player up
I modified the script to affect the movement of character controller on y-axis:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GavityZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float modifiedGravity = -20.0f;

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            // ensure we are retrieving the player components
            FPSInput playerMovement = other.GetComponent<FPSInput>();

            Debug.Log("fps input retrieved");
            // check if the collided object has an FPSInput component
            if (playerMovement != null)
            {

                Debug.Log("Applying gravity");

                playerMovement.gravity = modifiedGravity;

                playerMovement.velocity.y = Mathf.Max(playerMovement.velocity.y, playerMovement.gravity * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        // reset gravity to normal when the player exits the zone
        FPSInput playerMovement = other.GetComponent<FPSInput>();

        if (playerMovement != null)
        {
            playerMovement.gravity = -9.8f;
        }
    }
}

FPS script for reference
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
[AddComponentMenu("Control Script/FPS Input")]
public class FPSInput : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float movementSpeed = 2.0f;

    // creating variable to reference CharacterController
    private CharacterController charController;

    public float gravity = -9.8f;

    // variables for jumping
    public float jumpForce = 5.0f;
    public bool isGrounded = true;
    public bool isJumping = false;

    public Vector3 velocity;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // chnace this can be null, so we need to initalize at start
        // access other components attacehd to the same object
        charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementSpeed;

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, movementSpeed);

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                // apply jump force and set grounded and jumping flags 
                velocity.y = jumpForce;
                isGrounded = false;
                isJumping = true;
            }
        }

        // check if the player has landed back on the ground
        if (charController.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = 0; // reset the vertical velocity
            isGrounded = true; // set grounded flag to true
            isJumping = false; // set jumping flag to false
        }

        else
        {
            // apply gravity to the player's movement 
            velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // set the y-component of the movement vector to the current velocity 
        movement.y = velocity.y;
        movement *= Time.deltaTime;
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);

        // tell the charactercontroller to move with the vector
        charController.Move(movement);
    }
}```


How does the current behaviour of this code, after your modifications, differ from what you want? What should answers try to change about it?
